# svg as background wont show

Tags: css, svg, background

I've created a `.svg`-file in illustrator CS6. But when I try to add it as a background with CSS like this:

```
html { 
    background: url(/path/to/images/layout/backgound.svg) no-repeat top center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
 }
```

It won't show up.

Tried to remove the `background-size`-thing, but didn't help...
I use CodeKit to minify, and combine all CSS-files into one file. Tried to not do that, but didn't work either...

- I saved the file using SVG 1.1 profile
- Image location as "link"
- Encoding: "UTF-8"

What am I doing wrong?

If i go directrly to the image location in my browser, it appears. But it doesn't show up as the backgound on the site...

Here is a link to my site : http://kiledesign.no
Here is a direct link to the `.svg`: http://kiledesign.no/assets/images/layout/bg_svg/background.svg

EDIT: Changed to use CSS.MediaQuery and a couple of .jpg-images - for now...

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems you have to directly use the PNG inside your SVG (your SVG is actually just a PNG anyway) to make it work, otherwise the SVG is just rendered empty no matter in CSS background or HTML `<img>`: http://jsfiddle.net/8ELVD/

Comment: @Passerby "your SVG is actually just a PNG anyway" - uhm, where did this come from? EDIT: Oh, I see the SVG contains a raster image, nvm.

Comment: Your svg, http://kiledesign.no/assets/images/layout/bg_svg/background.svg, is essentially just a wrapper for a png image, so you could just use the png directly instead.

Comment: In other words - I'm doing this wrong? The image here is just about 50kb: http://alistapart.com/d/using-svg-for-flexible-scalable-and-fun-backgrounds-part-ii/example2.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an SVG file as an image of any kind (including as a background image) then it must be a single file for [privacy reasons](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=628747). Any external references to anything including external CSS or images will be ignored.

In your case your SVG file includes an external image file, you need to convert that image to a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) so that all of the image data is in the SVG file itself.

Comment: Managed to make it work. Thanks Robert. But the filesize is now 5.2mb (1920x1358px). Isn't that way too much for a background image? The MediaQuery-solution was 637kb in total - for three `.jpg` images in different sizes (1024x724px, 1380x905px, 1920x1358px). Is it because of the noisy background the filesize is so big? This image doesn't say anything about the dimensions of the image: http://alistapart.com/d/using-svg-for-flexible-scalable-and-fun-backgrounds-part-ii/example2.html - but mine does...

Comment: Base64 encoding is not that efficient, it will be just the same size in the browser's memory although it will take longer to transmit you could cancel that out by compressing it with gzip to make an .svgz file.

Comment: So, basically I'm doing this wrong then? How come the image at AListApart, that I linked to, is just about 50kb then? When I think about it, this is probably a different question...

Comment: Because that's uses SVG primitives (lines, polygons, arcs etc) to create the graphics and not a bitmap.

Comment: I think I understand now. When I moved it over to Photoshop to add the overlay colors and noise, it became bitmap. I guess I have to make the image simpler... Thanks for your reply - You've been very helpful.

Comment: I recreated the image in Illustrator - and now the filesize is just about 70kb with the same dimensions (1920×1358px), and I'm way more happier with the result.